# url_for in celery doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, celery

We are building a notofication mailing system as part of a python/flask system, as for now it has been run using cronjobs but we're moving everything to celery to make it more performant and easier to maintain.

However the templates which have been working so far suddendly start throwing the following error:

```
[2017-05-29 20:30:30,411: WARNING/PoolWorker-7] [2017-05-29 20:30:30,411] 
ERROR in mails: ERROR errorString => Could not build url for endpoint 
'page.start' with values ['from_email']. Did you mean 'static' instead?
```

The url_for is called in an external template as follows:

```
{{ url_for('page.start', _external=True) }}
```

and rendered as follows:

```
    message = render_template('notifs/user_notif.html',
                                      subject=subject,
                                      entries = grouped,
                                      user=u,
                                      unsubscribe_hash=pw_hash,
                                      list_id = str(notif_list.id),
                                      timestamp = today)
```

Now if we rip out all the url_for in the template it works. But why?
My hypothesis, which i can't test or proof: Somehow celery does not have access to the Blueprints (even though it is running in the application context, as the tasks actually accesses all kinds of models and the db etc.). How do I make celery understand url_for?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same issue:

The database and models are fronted by by your ORM (Flask-sqlalchemy?), not the Flask application itself. Flask the application provides the context for things like url_for, current_user, etc. Your orm just provides the database abstraction and is not contingent on the actual application context.